# Can a team member turn on Apple Pay if I set up the provisioning file for them?

Tags: ios, xcode, applepay

I have a team 'member' asking for 'Admin/Agent' so they can develop for Apple Pay.  If I set up the provisioning profile for them will they still need admin to turn on Apple Pay in the 'Capabilities' tab?

I do not want to give them admin if at all possible.

Xcode 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can toggle the Apple Pay Capability in the Capabilities Tab, they don't need to be admin for that. Although they need to have the Apple Pay certificate in their Keychain, and you, as an admin, have to generate it.

So the answer is Yes, it's possible but you have to do the admin work on the Apple Developer dashboard and pass everything they would need to them.